# How to filter JSON data from API by date range in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to filter the below JSON data by start date and end date, it should return the data between start date and end date, I tried to achieve using below code, but I'm doing wrong something to filter. I'm new to front end technologies like JavaScript. It would be appreciated if someone can correct me what I'm doing wrong here:

The API data is like that seen below

```
{
   "rec_id": 1,
   "emp_id": 1,
   "date": "Jan 22, 2020",
   "time_in": "09:20",
   "time_out": "19:56",
   "total_hours": 10.6,
   "weekday": 4,
   "name": "Carlina Dahlberg",
   "gender": "Female",
   "designation": "Supervisor",
   "department": "Production",
   "calculate": "",
   "basic_salary": 20000,
   "per_day_salary": 1000
 },
 {
   "rec_id": 2,
   "emp_id": 2,
   "date": "Jan 22, 2020",
   "time_in": "08:33",
   "time_out": "13:16",
   "total_hours": 4.72,
   "weekday": 4,
   "name": "Brenden Greenacre",
   "gender": "Male",
   "designation": "Executive",
   "department": "Marketing",
   "calculate": "",
   "basic_salary": 25000,
   "per_day_salary": 1250
 },
```

This is my code file

```
async function getData(){
   let myData = await fetch("http://34.198.81.140/attendance.json")
     .then((respose) => {
       return respose.json() 
     })
     .then((data) => {
       return data;
     });
   let startDate ="Feb 1, 2020";
   let endDate = "Feb 29, 2020";
   let result = myData.filter((data) => {
     return data.date >= startDate && data.date <=endDate;
   })
   console.log(result);
}
getData()
```

The data get filtered but not as per requirement, please see the  [screen shot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3npD.png) output. In the screen shot the Data come from 1 feb to 29 Feb but, the Data from 2 Feb to 9 Feb whole data is skip by filter function.

Comment: You need to convert both the dates (from the api and the filter) to date objects or timestamps, otherwise you're just comparing strings.

Comment: What kind of API is delivering dates in this format? Normally an API should deliver a timestamp or a ISO formatted date like 2021-08-18T09:45:00

Comment: Your dates are strings, so they are compared lexicographic, so "Feb 3" is greater than "Feb 29". Convert your strings to `Date` objects or ISO Format ( yyyy-MM-dd ) to make them comparable. If you have control over the server, you should preferably fix that at the server.

Comment: Btw you should not mix promise chaining (`.then(...)`) with `async/await` choose one and stick with it

Comment: @derpirscher I did not understood your last point

Comment: in your code you have something like `await promise1.then(...)` that's bad style and may lead to errors, therefore you should avoid it. Either use only promise chaining `fetch(...).then( ...).then(...).then(...).cacth(...)` or use only `let response await fetch(..); let json = await response.json(); ...`

Comment: @derpirscher, okay but if i removed the async/await from the promise chain then it throw type Error :"Uncaught TypeError: myData.filter is not a function"

Comment: @Akashkumar Well of course, then you will have to handle the filtering INSIDE the promise resolve hander. or you use multiple awaits. Something like `let response = await fetch(...);  let mydata = await response.json()`

Comment: @derpirscher can you share  a example  with me on this discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Urnary (`+`) operator, with `new Date()` to create a timestamp, and then you can compare the timestamps to get desired result.

```js
async function getData() {
  /* 
     let myData = await fetch("http://34.198.81.140/attendance.json")
       .then((respose) => {
         return respose.json() 
       })
       .then((data) => {
         return data;
       });*/

  // For Testing Purposes only  (data modified)  
  let myData = [{
      "rec_id": 1,
      "emp_id": 1,
      "date": "Jan 22, 2020",
      "time_in": "09:20",
      "time_out": "19:56",
      "total_hours": 10.6,
      "weekday": 4,
      "name": "Carlina Dahlberg",
      "gender": "Female",
      "designation": "Supervisor",
      "department": "Production",
      "calculate": "",
      "basic_salary": 20000,
      "per_day_salary": 1000
    },
    {
      "rec_id": 2,
      "emp_id": 2,
      "date": "Feb 5, 2020",
      "time_in": "08:33",
      "time_out": "13:16",
      "total_hours": 4.72,
      "weekday": 4,
      "name": "Brenden Greenacre",
      "gender": "Male",
      "designation": "Executive",
      "department": "Marketing",
      "calculate": "",
      "basic_salary": 25000,
      "per_day_salary": 1250
    }
  ]
  let startDate = +new Date("Feb 1, 2020");
  let endDate = +new Date("Feb 29, 2020");
  let result = myData.filter((data) => {
    return +new Date(data.date) >= startDate && +new Date(data.date) <= endDate;
  })
  console.log(result);
}
getData()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me, Now data came as per requirement

Comment: @AkashKumar Can you please accept the answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the date into something you can compare dates with.
There are a few options in front of you for that.

1. Rely on `Date.Parse()`, a bad idea  ref. ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#static_methods))
2. Use an alternative date library. A simple google search should reveal some.

After parsing the date, you can use the same logic that you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can do it through converting the strings of number into numbers. afterwards try comparing them with each other.
2. You can use `JS libraries` such as **`Moment.js`** or **`Dayjs`** as well to get around it.look through their APIs to dispel the snag you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below, if you decide to use async/await:

```
async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch('http://34.198.81.140/attendance.json')
  const myData = await response.json()
    
  let startDate = 'Feb 1, 2020'
  let endDate = 'Feb 29, 2020'
  let result = myData.filter(data => {
    return (
      // Convert all date values to javascript dates using new Date(value)
      // Get the number of milliseconds using getTime()
      // Compare the milliseconds values
      new Date(data.date).getTime() >= new Date(startDate).getTime() &&
      new Date(data.date).getTime() <= new Date(endDate).getTime()
    )
  })
  console.log(result)
}
getData()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me now data came as per requirement